# Does Ocelot supports secure Websockets (wss)

Tags: .net-6.0, ocelot

When I tried using Ocelot as a WebSocket proxy, I could not get it working for wss. I was able to see it working for ws.

When we are trying to proxy for wss getting decrypt operation failed while reading the bytes at the server side socket. With plan ws I am able to get this working.

Ocelot config as follows, where wss proxying is specified:

```
{
  "Routes": [
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/ws",
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/{anything}",
      "DownstreamScheme": "wss",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "127.0.0.1",
          "Port": 8080
        }
      ]      
    }
  ]
}
```

Websocket Server code which listens on port 8080:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Security.Authentication;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Server
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string ip = "127.0.0.1";
        int port = 8080;
        var server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(ip), port);

        server.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Server has started on {0}:{1}, Waiting for a connection...", ip, port);

        TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
        Console.WriteLine("A client connected.");



        byte[] pfxData = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\e409316\Desktop\test.pfx");
        var cert = new X509Certificate2(pfxData, "Password1", X509KeyStorageFlags.UserKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
        Stream sourceTcpStream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), false);
        (sourceTcpStream as SslStream).AuthenticateAsServer(
            cert,
            false,
            SslProtocols.Tls12, true);



        Stream stream = sourceTcpStream;//client.GetStream();
        //Stream stream = client.GetStream();

        // enter to an infinite cycle to be able to handle every change in stream
        while (true)
        {
            //while (!stream.DataAvailable) ;
            while (client.Available < 3) ; // match against "get"

            byte[] bytes = new byte[client.Available];
            stream.Read(bytes, 0, client.Available);
            string s = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);

            if (Regex.IsMatch(s, "^GET", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("=====Handshaking from client=====\n{0}", s);

                // 1. Obtain the value of the "Sec-WebSocket-Key" request header without any leading or trailing whitespace
                // 2. Concatenate it with "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11" (a special GUID specified by RFC 6455)
                // 3. Compute SHA-1 and Base64 hash of the new value
                // 4. Write the hash back as the value of "Sec-WebSocket-Accept" response header in an HTTP response
                string swk = Regex.Match(s, "Sec-WebSocket-Key: (.*)").Groups[1].Value.Trim();
                string swka = swk + "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11";
                byte[] swkaSha1 = System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1.Create().ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(swka));
                string swkaSha1Base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(swkaSha1);

                // HTTP/1.1 defines the sequence CR LF as the end-of-line marker
                byte[] response = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
                    "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\n" +
                    "Connection: Upgrade\r\n" +
                    "Upgrade: websocket\r\n" +
                    "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: " + swkaSha1Base64 + "\r\n\r\n");

                stream.Write(response, 0, response.Length);
            }
            else
            {
                bool fin = (bytes[0] & 0b10000000) != 0,
                    mask = (bytes[1] & 0b10000000) != 0; // must be true, "All messages from the client to the server have this bit set"

                int opcode = bytes[0] & 0b00001111, // expecting 1 - text message
                    msglen = bytes[1] - 128, // & 0111 1111
                    offset = 2;

                if (msglen == 126)
                {
                    // was ToUInt16(bytes, offset) but the result is incorrect
                    msglen = BitConverter.ToUInt16(new byte[] { bytes[3], bytes[2] }, 0);
                    offset = 4;
                }
                else if (msglen == 127)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("TODO: msglen == 127, needs qword to store msglen");
                    // i don't really know the byte order, please edit this
                    // msglen = BitConverter.ToUInt64(new byte[] { bytes[5], bytes[4], bytes[3], bytes[2], bytes[9], bytes[8], bytes[7], bytes[6] }, 0);
                    // offset = 10;
                }

                if (msglen == 0)
                    Console.WriteLine("msglen == 0");
                else if (mask)
                {
                    byte[] decoded = new byte[msglen];
                    byte[] masks = new byte[4] { bytes[offset], bytes[offset + 1], bytes[offset + 2], bytes[offset + 3] };
                    offset += 4;

                    for (int i = 0; i < msglen; ++i)
                        decoded[i] = (byte)(bytes[offset + i] ^ masks[i % 4]);

                    string text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decoded);
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}", text);
                }
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("mask bit not set");

                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Websocket Client code which tries to connect to ocelot endpoint (upstream endpoint on port 5000):

```
ClientWebSocket client = new ClientWebSocket();
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
client.ConnectAsync(new Uri("wss://127.0.0.1:5000/"), CancellationToken.None).Wait();
var buffer = new byte[]{1,2,3};
client.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), WebSocketMessageType.Text, true,CancellationToken.None);
```

Error: The decryption operation failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it to be a certificate validity issue. Solved it by using a trusted certificate.